# CSS making inner div match outer div height

Tags: css

I'm basically making a form (screenshot: http://mason.gmu.edu/~vnguyenl/form.jpg) where there are 2 columns. The label column and the input column. The label side is in a div that has its own bg color, and same with the input field side. I'm trying to make it so that if there's to much text on one side than the other column will match it's height. Right now, if one side is larger than the other, there are gaps. Would appreciate any help! Thanks.

The html for the form looks like the following:

```
<div class="formRow">
<div class="labelColumn">Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: Last Name: <span class="required">*</span></div>
<div class="contentcolumn">
    <input class="textBox300" type="text" id="last_name"  tabindex="1"  />
</div>
</div>
```

The css is the following:

```
#pt-profile-form .labelColumn, .labelColumn2 {
font-weight:bold;
float:left;
width:300px; /* Width of left column */
margin-left:0px;
background:#f0f4f7;
text-align:left;
padding:5px;
padding-left:14px;
display:block;
white-space:normal;
position:relative;
clear:both;
}

#pt-profile-form .formRow { clear:both; height:100%;  }

#pt-profile-form .contentcolumn, .contentcolumn2 {
margin-left:320px; /* Set left margin to LeftColumnWidth */
background-color:#eae9d7;
padding:5px;
text-align:left;
vertical-align:middle;
position:relative;
}

#pt-profile-form .labelColumn, .contentcolumn {
/*height:30px;*/
min-height:30px;
height:100%;
}

#pt-profile-form .labelColumn2, .contentcolumn2 { /* column properties for <textarea>     */
/*height:100px;*/
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Check out: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: This too: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution**

As far as I can see the only way to achieve this is to put the background color on the wrapping element (in your case `<div class="formRow">`) and then ensure that wrapping element is pushed to the full height by use of clearing, as @MarcB mentioned in his comment ( http://quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html ).

So the following CSS should fix it:

```
.formRow {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #EAE9D7;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/qnRgL/

The one caveat with this solution is that it will hide overflowing content. If you need overflowing content to be displayed try the alternate solution instead.

---

**Alternate clearing solution**

If changing the `overflow` property causes problems for any reason, another solution is to add generated content using the `:after` pseudo-element. E.g.:

```
.formRow:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #EAE9D7;
}
```

See under `Generating Content Through CSS`:
http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/

Note however that this solution will not work in IEs 6 and 7.

Comment: As a side note about CSS best practice: some people (including myself) nowadays think that use of IDs in CSS should be avoided completely - as they complicate cascading rules and actually don't offer any problem-solving benefits over classes - if possible, and also that the simplest possible CSS rule to achieve the effect should always be used - don't add unnecessary specificity. A source: http://csslint.net/about.html

Comment: Thanks Robin! I'll play around with that. I also appreciate the side note. I've just started doing front-end 6 months ago so I appreciate the little rules and habits I should follow. I've been actually trying to find a good article on current common standards if you know any. Thanks!

Comment: The link I posted above - http://csslint.net/about.html - has some great advice. Apart from that here are other good articles about best practice: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/css-best-practices/, http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/05/10-best-css-practices-to-improve-your-code/. As I say I think you should *only* use IDs for anchors in your content (e.g. `index.html#introduction`), never for CSS. The best solution for alternative styles for Internet Explorer is the one used on HTML5 Boilerplate: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/.

Comment: If you think my solution solved your problem, could you set it as the accepted solution? Ta.